Export Entra Audit Logs via powershell
I am trying to export the Microsoft Entra ID Audit logs, specifically looking for the logs of all MFA/Phone app updates or changes, so this log or portion of log can be email to our sec ops team.
The values I have identified are:
Log file example:

my thought was to export the audit logs, then attach the csv to an email
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$filename = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd" 
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDateTime gt $date" |
    Export-Csv -Path c:\install.tmp\$filename.csv

in the exported file where I would expect the details I need I only get.


would you be fine with an answer using Graph instead of AzureAD? AzureAD Module targets a different API that is in process of deprecation. You should consider migrating your code. If so, see the Json response from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, which properties are you interested in exporting?

In your log file example that you identified, you show Service, Category, Activity, Result, and ResultReason. In your output you only show what you get for TargetResources and AdditionalDetails. Why are you not showing what the columns you care about are showing? You completely left out all the categories your desired example shows. This is not going to help us help you.

@DougMaurer Try adding -NoTypeInformation at the end in the export-csv step and check


I agree with @Santiago Squarzon, you can switch to Microsoft Graph PowerShell commands as Azure AD module is about to be deprecated soon.

Initially, I too got similar response when I tried to export the audit logs directly without iterating target resources:
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
Connect-MgGraph

$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
$filename = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

# Retrieve directory audit logs filtering  authentication methods of users only
$auditLogs = Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "LoggedByService eq 'Authentication Methods' and Category eq 'UserManagement' and activityDateTime ge $date"

$auditLogs | Export-Csv -Path "c:\test_csv\$filename.csv" 


To resolve this, you can make use of below modified script that exports data with target resources details successfully like this:
Connect-MgGraph

$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
$filename = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

$auditLogs = Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "LoggedByService eq 'Authentication Methods' and Category eq 'UserManagement' and activityDateTime ge $date"

$formattedLogs = @()

foreach ($log in $auditLogs) {
    $targetResources = $log.TargetResources | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Id = $_.Id
            Type = $_.Type
            DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
            UserPrincipalName = $_.UserPrincipalName 
        }
    }

    $additionalDetails = $log.AdditionalDetails | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Key = $_.Key
            Value = $_.Value
        }
    }

    $formattedLog = [PSCustomObject]@{
        ActivityDateTime = $log.ActivityDateTime
        ActivityDisplayName = $log.ActivityDisplayName
        Category = $log.Category
        Result = $log.Result
        ResultReason = $log.ResultReason
        TargetResources = $targetResources
        AdditionalDetails = $additionalDetails
    }
    $formattedLogs += $formattedLog
}

$formattedLogs | Export-Csv -Path "c:\test_csv\$filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Response:


Reference:
List directoryAudits - Microsoft Graph
